# how to name the folders for multisite in drupal locally?

Tags: drupal

i am creating multisite in drupal 6 in my local xampp server,could anyone help me to name the subfolders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name the sites folders the same as you would in production.

```
example.com
example2.com
....
```

Then make entries in your hosts file on your computer.

```
notepad C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

127.0.0.1 localtest.example.com
127.0.0.1 localtest.example2.com
```

Then you can build the sites locally using the names localtest.example.com and when you move the site to a production server it will work exactly the same with www.example.com

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [MultiSite HowTo's](http://drupal.org/node/43816) at Drupal. There is a massive collection for many different versions and environments. There is also a link to ["Multi-Sites Using XAMPP on Windows XP"](http://drupal.org/node/166831) (can be used for any win versin)